# Java Socket waiting for UTF8

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to implement a client-server application by myself. Its working so far, except the fact, that when I am accessing the port via another application (e.g. Web-Browser) the server application is blocking.

Is there any easy way/good practice to check, if the connecting application is the "client application"?

Here is an short example for a socket listening to port 8080. The socket awaits 2 Strings. If you now connect with the browser (localhost:8080) the connection gets established, but is waiting for the first UTF8.

```
public class MainSocket {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    try {            
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection established");
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
                in.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: DataInputStream is designed for read *binary* data, not text.  I suggest using one of the many Reader implementations for reading text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `DataInputStream.readUTF8`. That expects data like this:

> First, two bytes are read and used to construct an unsigned 16-bit integer in exactly the manner of the readUnsignedShort method . This integer value is called the UTF length and specifies the number of additional bytes to be read. These bytes are then converted to characters by considering them in groups. The length of each group is computed from the value of the first byte of the group. The byte following a group, if any, is the first byte of the next group.

(etc)

In other words, this isn't just UTF-8. It's a slight variation on UTF-8 *with a length prefix*. That's not what a browser is going to write to the connection. Basically, `DataInput` and `DataOutput` are symmetric but not entirely general-purpose - they're usually used together, with one side reading via `DataInput` what the other side has written with `DataOutput`.

If you just want to read lines of UTF-8, you can use:

```
try (Reader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputReader)) {
    System.out.println(read.readLine());
    System.out.println(read.readLine());
}
```

(Now it's not at all clear that you should expect a browser to write UTF-8 to the socket either, but the above is more likely to get you to the next step, I'd say...)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. This is exactly the problem I am facing. From my client Application I am writing 2*UTF and 1*File to the server. But now, if I am accessing the port of the server via the browser, the Server is blocking because it is waiting for the first readUTF.

Comment: @AndreasFreitag: Well yes - if your client application and a browser are going to make different requests, why would you try to handle them on the same port?

Comment: They are using different ports, but if a User is accessing the 8080 port, the  server is blocked. In the real server application I am using a socket pool with 10 sockets, so it is not a big problem. But in my opinion its not a good practice.

Comment: @AndreasFreitag: Well it sounds like the problem is more a threading problem than anything else - either use asynchronous IO, or use a different thread for each connection.

Comment: I am sorry! Not the server is blocked, only 1 socket of the connection pool. But if 10 user would do it at the same time, there would be problems. And I cannot accept more connections, because of the licensing of the software I am starting from there.

Comment: So implement a timeout of some description - annoying to do, but it shouldn't be too bad. If any request takes too long, close the socket associated with that request.